# Using both HTTPS and HTTP schemes using single connection pool

Tags: apache, https, connection-pooling, url-scheme

Can I have a common connection pool for both http and https?
If yes, how can I configure it?

This is my connection pool manager

```
public class PoolConnectionManager {

private static PoolConnectionManager instance;
private static CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = null;
public static RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setSocketTimeout(5000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000)
        .setConnectTimeout(5000).build();



public static synchronized PoolConnectionManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (PoolConnectionManager.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new PoolConnectionManager();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

private PoolConnectionManager() {
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(50);
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
}

public CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
    return HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(this.poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();         
}

public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager getPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager() {
    return poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
}
```

}

Should I have another method called getHttpsClient() and set the certificate and trust store etc?

Comment: More information please. Why do you need this?

Comment: I'm wondering if for your use case you could create a wrapper class that has underlying connection managers - one for each of HTTP and HTTPS and have wrapper methods that call each of the members as appropriate. I don't see an advantage of this over having 2 separate connection managers though.

Comment: I integrate with a couple of third party providers . One uses https and one uses http. That's why wanted to understand if that is possible at all. And the one that uses https has a self signed certificate for the development environment, so in addition to using https, I am setting trust all stores property for me to able to do ssl handshake successfully.(only in dev env though)

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do it, but there will be others more knowledgeable about this than me who may have a suggestion.